# Module, vector space and abelian group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, vector-spaces, modules

please can someone help me to prove this two properties

$\bullet$ If K is a field, then the concept of K-vector space (a vector space over K) and K-module are identical.

$\bullet$ The concept of a Z-module agrees with the notion of an abelian group.

please

thank you.

Comment: Hint: If $G$ is an abelian group, then $(n,x) \mapsto x^n$ defines an action of $\mathbb{Z}$ on $G$. Can you check this?

Comment: I don't understand what i must see with this ?,if i suppose that (M,+,.)is a module on $\mathbb{Z}$ then i have directly that $(M,+)$ is an abelien group , i dont think that is suffisant ?

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan are you sure that is $(n,x)\mapsto x^n$

Answer (score 1):

You should just take the definitions of the objects you mention and compare them.